# Django migration with uuid field generates duplicated values

Tags: python, django, uuid, django-migrations

I have a `uuid` field (not a primary key). The generated migration is:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
import uuid


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ....
    ]

    operations = [
        ...
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='device',
            name='uuid',
            field=models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True),
        ),
        ...
    ]
```

But when doing `python manage.py migrate` it is crashing with:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: could not create unique index
>   "restaurants_device_uuid_key" DETAIL:  Key
>   (uuid)=(f3858ded-b8e0-4ac0-8436-8a61b10efc73) is duplicated.

Strangely enough, the problem does not seem to occur with primary keys (which are maybe created by the database, and not internally by django?)

How can I add a uuid field, and make sure that migrations work?

Comment: The docs explain this pretty well, see [Migrations that add unique fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields).

Comment: @knbk: Thanks. That is amazing. Amaizingly interesting and amazingly complex. Just .. to .. generate .. uuids

Comment: Alternatively, it's a hack but gives a similar functionality, and way simpler: str_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=36,default=lambda:str(uuid.uuid4())). After migration, run a loop for each object in the model and save() it to get a unique uuid. You don't need a unique index because the chances of the same uuid4 are near zero.

Comment: @AviahLaor: interesting workaround. My solution was even simpler: remove the `unique=True` constraint. The UUIDs are going to come from the frontend anyway (they refer to mobile devices), so technically I do not even need a default. It is a bit weird, because they really must be unique, but I could not get it to work with `default=None` and `unique=True`, which is actually what I wanted: they must be unique as long as they are not empty. I do not know even if django (or the database backend) supports that kind of constraint.

Comment: Actually yes, the whole idea of UUID is that it's unique no matter where it was created

Comment: @AviahLaor: but does django support a "unique or None" constraint?

Comment: hmmm... never thought of it that way. But effectively, a uuid field that allows blank, is unique or none index!

Comment: @knbk Thanks for the hint!, I solved my issue by wrapping up all the scripts from the docs to single migrations files. No need to create 2 empty migration scripts

Comment: The Django documentation suggests creating three migration files to add the new UUID field. An easier way is to add the gen_uuid method into the original migration, change unique=True to null=True in the AddField operation, add the RunPython operation underneath and then follow it with than AlterField operation that replaces the null=True with unique=True. Only a single migration required.

Comment: For whomever stumbles upon this...the link in first comment is broken. Please refer to this [one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields)

Comment: When the migration crashes, it seems to leave the db and Django in a broken state :/ The migration isn't registred as being run (in showmigrations) but it still has fiddled with the db. I guess the ALTER TABLE ops can't be transacted :)

Answer (score 68):

Here is an example doing everything in one single migration thanks to a RunPython call.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
import uuid


def create_uuid(apps, schema_editor):
    Device = apps.get_model('device_app', 'Device')
    for device in Device.objects.all():
        device.uuid = uuid.uuid4()
        device.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('device_app', 'XXXX'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='device',
            name='uuid',
            field=models.UUIDField(blank=True, null=True),
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(create_uuid),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='device',
            name='uuid',
            field=models.UUIDField(unique=True)
        )
    ]
```

Comment: But isn't there a race condition here? If user is edited while `create_uuid` is running, their data will be overwritten (granted, Django tries to lock the table to prevent that). Instead, it should be `device.save(update_fields=['uuid'])`, as in the Django docs.

Comment: This answer does not reference the related docs, and does not provide any explanation

Comment: Using this, I get `cannot ALTER TABLE "table_model" because it has pending trigger events`

Comment: Are you sure your  create_uuid function filled the field for every instance? This can happen if some Device avec an uuid set to None.

Answer (score 36):

(Answer taken from the first comment)

See the django docs - [Migrations that add unique fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields)

They recommend changing your single migration into three separate migrations:

1. Create field, set to null but not unique
2. Generate unique UUIDs
3. Alter the field to be unique

Comment: Also, it appears that they have an inaccuracy in their documentation. They are setting the field to unique in the very first migration, which is incorrect. You rightly point out that it should be set to null first, then created, then populated, then set to unique.

Comment: @MadPhysicist not sure if they've updated the docs, but they do now specify that you need to change unique to null in the first migration.

Comment: unique fields can have null nowadays, so this should not be necessary... ? i.e. I think you can create and migrate to a new field with unique=True, null=True

Answer (score 3):

In the mode, you have configured, that you want unique values for the uuid fields, but with default values(the same for all). So if you have two 'device' objects in the database, the migrations add 'uuid' field to them with the default 'uuid.uuid4' value and when it tries to set it to the second one, it crashes because of the unique constrains.

If you drop your db and create new objects probably there will be not problems but thats not a solution for production db obviously :D.

A better solution is to create a data migration which sets different uuid value (generated by the default 'uuid' library) to every existing object in the database. You can read more about data migrations here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

Then, when you create new objects, django will generate different uuid automatically. ;)

For the primary keys: Django adds it to the model by default.

Answer (score -1):

You can provide a management command to populate the uuid field after uu_id column is created in the model but this has to be done after migrating the model and setting the field default as None:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.apps import apps
import uuid


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        classes()


def classes():
    app_models = apps.get_app_config('appname').get_models()
    for model in app_models:
        field = None
        try:
            field = model._meta.get_field('uu_id')
        except:
            pass

        if field:

            uu_id_list = list(model.objects.all().values_list('uu_id',flat=True))
            if None in uu_id_list:
                for row in model.objects.all():
                    row.uu_id = uuid.uuid4()
                    row.save()
```