# Generating UUID in Django migrations (RunPython) is generating identical UUID

Tags: python, django, database-migration, uuid

Similarly to the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35281003/django-migration-with-uuid-field-generates-duplicated-values?rq=1), I'm trying to add a unique UUID field to a database table with existing rows. I've tried to follow the instructions and break down the migration into 3 operations:

```
def create_user_id(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model('authentication', 'User')
    for instance in User.objects.all():
        if not instance.user_id:
            instance.user_id = uuid.uuid4()
            instance.save(update_fields=['user_id'])

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('authentication', '0002_auto_20180101_1422'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='user',
            name='user_id',
            field=models.UUIDField(blank=True, editable=False, null=True),
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(create_user_id),
        migrations.AlterField(
           model_name='user',
           name='user_id',
           field=models.UUIDField(blank=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, null=True, unique=True),
    )
    ]
```

However I still get an integrity error on the 3rd operation. Closer inspection shows that the created user_id's are all identical. What could be causing this?

Comment: try to remove `if not instance.user_id:` i think the main logic error here.

Comment: I just tried it and it seems to have worked. I don't quite understand what the issue was though. @BearBrown any ideas?