# Django migration adding a UUIDField with a default

Tags: django, postgresql, django-migrations

I have a simple Django migration where I've added a `UUIDField` to the `Invoice` model as follows.

**Model field**:

```
uuid = models.UUIDField(
    _('Unique invoice ID'),
    default=uuid.uuid4,
    editable=False,
)
```

**Generated migration**:

```
migrations.AddField(
    model_name='invoice',
    name='uuid',
    field=models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, 
    verbose_name='Unique invoice ID'),
),
```

When I run this migration, every invoice gets the same UUID value as the others, almost as if the `uuid.uuid4` function is called once and then that value is reused for all objects.

I use PostgreSQL and Django 1.11.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: related: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25007

Comment: As well as: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Yikes! I'll accept your answer if your formulate those links into one. Thanks.

Comment: this is already being extensively discussed (and answered) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35281003

Answer (score 0):

[Docs on writing migrations that add unique fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields).

It is indeed called once, so you have to break the operations into steps.