# Unique URL generator for Object Items or hiding ID from URL parameter

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am working on an application built using Python3 and Django that generates PDFs (via HTML) using filled fields from a data model. 
I've created a URL function that takes a value of document ID and type, and then generates a PDF of that document.

What I want to do is to email clients a link that contains that URL function with a specific document ID, however, the problem that I'm facing is that the generated URL has the document ID in the URL parameter, and this is terrible for security purposes as all they can do is change ID number on URL and get access to a different document (that they are not supposed to see)

My questions are:

A- Is there a way to create a unique link for every generated PDF that I can send to clients?

B- Would it be better to create another field in the model of a randomly generated 15 character value, that I use instead of the ID in the parameter?

Comment: Are you using FileField in django model to store the file?

Comment: No, the file is generated at every visit of the URL via write_pdf() function

Comment: Oh so I think you can use uuid to generate a unique id and then use that as the name of the file and send it to your clients.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for! But I am facing a problem, you see I added this `random_string_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)` to my model, but all the documents have the same UUID number, which defeats the purpose. 
I cannot use it as PK as I am already using ID as PK in many other places. Thank you so much for your help! @ToanQuocHo

Comment: Also worth mentioning that when I add `unique= True` I get a "Duplicate Entry" error in the DB

Comment: You could customize your model save method to filter by uuid before saving your model, if there is any record which have the same uuid then just need to issue a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I have fixed it by doing the following:

1- UUID was definetly the way, thank you @Toan Quoc Ho for that suggestion. I have added a UUID field to each of the models,

2- Because I wanted to keep my PK as ID, I had the problem of generating unique UUID fields of existing documents. So I followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35281003/django-migration-with-uuid-field-generates-duplicated-values/46281363#46281363), and it worked magically. Only thing to note **is that there can be no traffic when applying these changes, otherwise the database will crash, be aware.**

3- I, then, used the UUID together with ID to determine documents and passed them as URL parameters using regex as (\d+)/([\w-]+)

Voila, that did exactly what I wanted. No two documents share the same UUID, and vice-versa. I could generate a link unique to each document, and block any other access.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the new `secrets` module available in Python 3.6+. Here is an example:

```
from secrets import token_urlsafe
random_string = token_urlsafe(16)
print(random_string)
```

The result would be something like this - `nslhgo0dYowR6CvMDEwC_A`.