# Django model add uuid

Tags: django, model, migration, field, uuid

Django 2.2
postgres

I added uuid to my existing django model , generated and applied a migration for the table that already had records in it:

```
migrations.AddField(
    model_name='<mymodel>',
    name='uuid',
    field=models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False),
),
```

The field got added fine, however all the existing records got the same value inserted in the uuid field. How do I make default=uuid.uuid4 to generate a new uuid value for each existing records?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add Unique constraint for unique id for every model

```
uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
```

Then your migrations will look like this

```
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name=<<model_name>>,
            name='uuid',
            field=models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True),
        ),
```

Given that you have added import uuid.

When you run migrations now it will show error that your previous records contain same values which **conflicts** with the unique constriant so you might be looking forward to remove or override previous records to resolve this possible conflict.

Comment: When I drop the column from the table and try to re-apply migration that adds uuid field (now with unique=True), the migration dies with this error and no uuid field gets added: 

`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: could not create unique index "accbarcode_<mymodel>_uuid_key"
DETAIL:  Key (uuid)=(a6ba0190-3782-49c0-8b78-5c102c69cf86) is duplicated.`

Is this the conflict you are talking about?

Comment: This thread answers how to apply migrations when this occurs:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35281003/django-migration-with-uuid-field-generates-duplicated-values

Answer (score 2):

Turned out you can't do it through normal django migration procedure (makemigrations / migrate). You have to do it as a custom 3 migrations, the procedure is described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields . Thanks to [Muhammad Hashir Hassan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11979793/muhammad-hashir-hassan) for pointing me to the discussion on the subject where I found this link to the documentaipon.

Comment: This is the correct approach as described in the link in the answer. This remains true even for the latest version (3.1 as of the writing of this comment). See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields.